# Reading a matrix from excel and loop through using c# DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, matrix, webforms

I am reading an excel that contains a matrix table like the following: 
[image]

I need to enter the values into an SQL table with the following syntax:

`insert into t values (1,18,1.943)`

`insert into t values (1,18,1.524)`

`insert into t values (1,18,1.395)`

etc

what I tried to do is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ReadExcelFile(Server.MapPath("/Migration/" + txtExcelName.Text + ".xlsx"), false);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            DataRow myrow = null;
            DataColumn mycol = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                myrow = dt.Rows[i];
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    myrow = dt.Rows[i +1];
                }

                for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    mycol = dt.Columns[j];
                    try
                    {
                        str.Append("insert into HousingLoanInsuranceRate values (" + dt.Rows[i][mycol] + "," + myrow[0] + ",'" + dt.Rows[i+1][mycol] + "',0,0)");
                        str.Append("<br/>");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }


            }
            litMessage.Text += str.ToString();
        }
```

But it seems my code is not returning the wished result

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Shouldn't "`insert into t values (1,18,1.524)`" be "`insert into t values (2,18,1.524)`", and "`insert into t values (1,18,1.395)`" be "`insert into t values (3,18,1.395)`"?

Comment: no it shouldn't as this is the logic that i want to go through the table

Comment: Then just remove `dt.Rows[i][mycol]` and hardcode `1` instead? And maybe replace `dt.Rows[i+1][mycol]` with `myrow[j]`?

Comment: but it should not always be 1, it should be 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Well this is exactly what I asked in my first comment, and you answered "no"

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // start from 1
{
    myrow = dt.Rows[i];
    //if (i == 0)
    //{
    //    myrow = dt.Rows[i +1];
    //}

    for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        try
        {
            // CHANGES MADE HERE ---------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------------vvvvvvvv
            str.Append("insert into HousingLoanInsuranceRate values ("+ dt.Rows[0][j] + "," + myrow[0] + "," + myrow[j] + ",0,0)");
            str.Append("<br/>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This should fix your problem.
However, be aware that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider using parameterized query.